# The '@JoinColumn' for a secondary table must reference the primary key

Tags: java-17, hibernate-6.x, spring-boot-3

I am migrating a spring boot 2.x component to 3.1.5 (latest as of now)

I am encountering a new hibernate error (hibernate 6.2.9) which was working fine with Hibernate (5.x)

For brevity I am not adding entire entities. Only the needed parts. Following line taken from `TickersAll` entity.

```
@JsonIgnore
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "COMPANY_TICKERS",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TICKER_SERIAL", referencedColumnName = "TICKER_SERIAL")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID", referencedColumnName = "COMPANY_ID")})
private CCPCompany ccpCompany;
```

The associated `CCPCompany` entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
public class CCPCompany {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "SEQ_COMPANY_ID")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "SEQ_COMPANY_ID", allocationSize = 1, name = "SEQ_COMPANY_ID")
    @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID", nullable = false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long companyId;

    // other columns
}
```

This is a ManyToOne relationship that uses a separate table `COMPANY_TICKERS`. The table is this:

```
create table company_tickers
(
    company_id        numeric(10)                                not null
        constraint fk_company_tickers_companies
            references dfn_universal_data.companies,
    ticker_serial     numeric(20)                                not null
        constraint uk_comp_tck_ticker_serial
            unique,
    language_id       varchar(2) default 'EN'::character varying not null
        constraint fk_company_tickers_lang
            references dfn_universal_data.languages,
    description       varchar(500),
    lastupdated       timestamp,
    last_updated_time timestamp  default sysdate,
    constraint pk_company_tickers
        primary key (company_id, ticker_serial, language_id)
);
```

When starting the application, as soon as it registers the datasource beans, hibernate throws following exception and shuts down.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: The '@JoinColumn' for a secondary table must reference the primary key
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.TableBinder.bindNonPrimaryKeyReference(TableBinder.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.TableBinder.bindExplicitColumns(TableBinder.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.TableBinder.bindForeignKey(TableBinder.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.bindJoinToPersistentClass(EntityBinder.java:1864)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.createPrimaryColumnsToSecondaryTable(EntityBinder.java:1813)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.EntityBinder.finalSecondaryTableBinding(EntityBinder.java:1783)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.SecondaryTableSecondPass.doSecondPass(SecondaryTableSecondPass.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1870)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1823)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

What primary key is hibernate expecting? I removed the referenced column from the ccp company join column and it is starting fine. But I am not sure why it fails in the first place?
This works:

```
@JsonIgnore
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "COMPANY_TICKERS",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "TICKER_SERIAL")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_ID")})
private CCPCompany ccpCompany;
```

I am not sure what they changed in hibernate 6. Checked their migration guide as well as docs. No clue. Can someone clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem in `referencedColumnName = "TICKER_SERIAL"`. Looks like `TICKER_SERIAL` is not a primary key of `TickersAll`. Hibernate is expecting PK in this case because you're using `@ManyToOne`: if `TICKER_SERIAL` is not PK, then a few `TickersAll` may have the same `CCPCompany`, so logically it should be `@ManyToMany`.